# What is the required complexity of a function to not be bound by main memory?

Tags: c++, c, performance, assembly, x86

I know that accessing main memory has a high latency if data is not cached. This question is about *throughput*.

What is the required complexity of a function to never be bound by main memory on a regular desktop PC?

I read about modern RAM having a bandwidth of 25-30GB/s (DDR3 RAM, dual channel mode). As far as I can tell, a single core of a modern Intel processor can store at most 32 Byte per instruction using modern SIMD instruction sets. and it can run at most 4*10^9 instructions. So effectively, it can output about 120GB/s. Given a processor with 8 threads, the maximum output amount would be about 960GB/s as a worst case estimate.

The processor can put out at most ~36 times the data that can be written to RAM. Is it safe to assume that any function that runs non-load/store operations for more than 36 cycles per SIMD store or load (or more than 9 cycles per regular 8 Byte store or load) will never ever be bound by the main memory? Can this estimate be lowered significantly or is it too low for some reasons?

Given that I have:

```
X = (x_1, x_2, ..., x_n) // dataset, large enough to make good use of caches
a(x), b(x), c(x, y), d(x) := c(a(x), b(x)) // functions that operate on elements
A(x) := (a(x_1), a(x_2), ..., a(x_n)) // functions that operate on data sets
```

I am looking for guidelines when it is better (or not worse) to implement

```
D(X)
```

as

```
C(A(X), B(X))
```

given that the first implementation puts more pressure on caches and registers and the second implementation has more load/store operations.

(Of course, you can tell me to benchmark stuff, I am fine with that. But sometimes, I just want to make an educated guess and only revisit stuff, when it becomes a problem or bottle neck later on.)

Comment: @RossRidge That's good to know regarding terminology. I edited this question to refer to the operations as load/store operations. The point of the question is still valid, though?

Comment: Well, I think the answer is that it depends. Effective CPU speed drops dramatically when executing code with branches that can't be predicted, while effective DRAM speed also drops dramatically for small random accesses.

Comment: I believe the formula is still the same: bandwidth/load size = number of loads per second; From there: cycles per (cached) load / frequency of CPU = seconds per load; (1-secs per load)/loads per sec = time to waste between loads; time to waste * frequency = cycles to waste between loads. If my back of the fag packet calculation is correct (which I doubt).

Comment: @MargaretBloom Thanks, this seems to be in line with my own calculation.

Comment: @MargaretBloom Well, no, the goal is calculate the required complexity of a function that isn't memory bound. If the effective memory bandwidth can change independent of the complexity then that means the answer changes accordingly. You'll get a much bigger number if the 8 byte loads are random rather than sequential. You get a smaller number (measured by nominal instruction throughput) for a given function if it causes stalls because of mispredicted branches or some other hazard. These factors can potentially change depending on the data independent of anything else.

Comment: @RossRidge What does complexity mean in this context?

Comment: @MargaretBloom I don't know exactly, the original poster didn't define it. Given your "cycles to waste" definition, the number depends on the effective memory bandwidth, which depends (among many other things) on the access pattern. Whether or not hazards effect the number depend on how you're counting cycles. An "educated guess" based on adding up published instruction timings (or assuming 1 instruction = 1 cycle as the OP may be doing) isn't going to account for CPU stalls. Even benchmarking may not get the correct number when the actual number of cycles is data dependent.

Comment: @RossRidge Yeah, right. I assumed a sequential access with no hazards or stalls. In a way, the best scenario where the only limiting factor is the memory bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

I think it very much depends on whether the code is written in such a way that the CPU can prefetch the next data item into cache.  If it prefetches the wrong data then you'll still be memory bound regardless of the amount of time you spend processing the current data.

And if you have multiple threads writing to the same address (their data will be on different cache lines) then even if it has been prefetched correctly, if another thread has written to that address then it has to be dumped and re-read from main memory again.

In summary I think it's not possible to reason about these kind of things at this level and it will depend on the exact scenario you have.